# Java Path is not getting recognized in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

So, I am trying to install **Hadoop 3.3.0** on my **Windows 10** system, and after successfully updating the binaries and setting the Environment paths properly, I am getting a `not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.` error while I try to run the HDFS.

A quick search of past questions here mentioned that it may be due to space in the environment path. But I believe that is not the case here.

I am attaching my environment paths for Java and Hadoop below along with the error that pops up.

`HADOOP_HOME: C:\hadoop-3.3.0`

`JAVA_HOME: C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_271`

Error as displayed in cmd:

```
C:\hadoop-3.3.0\sbin>start-dfs

'C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_271\bin\java -Xmx32m -classpath "C:\hadoop-3.3.0\etc\hadoop;C:\hadoop-3.3.0\share\hadoop\common;C:\hadoop-3.3.0\share\hadoop\common\lib\*;C:\hadoop-3.3.0\share\hadoop\common\*" org.apache.hadoop.util.PlatformName' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Is there a tutorial you are following for the Hadoop install on Win 10? If so, can you provide us with the link? I think a bunch of environment paths are yet to be set, like `HADOOP_HDFS_HOME` and the `YARN_HOME` ones, but we need some more information about the whole procedure of installing.

Comment: Thank you for your time.  I am following a youtube tutorial video, link : https://youtu.be/GfixwKmS8Ro

Comment: Weird. It seems like your error output might not have to do with the Hadoop setup but the Java setup itself. The tutorial indicates the installation of jdk1.8.0_261 but you seem to have installed jdk1.8.0_271. Is it a choice of yours (like what you had before) or is it the latest version _after_ the tutorial was uploaded? Or was _271_ a typo while setting up the env var like the tutorial in 6:52? Try to install this version of java and test it out.

Comment: It certainly has some catch to it which I am yet to figure out. As of the version, yeah 271 was the latest java version. It is the latest version(after the tutorial was released)

Comment: In general, Hadoop on windows just never works as expected. Is there a reason why you cannot use Linux VM? Or download the preindtalled Cloudera sandbox?